# Continuous function, not on reals: each value twice?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

The non-existence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ which attain each value in their range exactly twice has been raised numerous times, yet I cannot find (either here or elsewhere) analogous theorems for $\mathbb{R}^n$ or other metric/topological spaces.

All I can observe is that on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, a counterexample would be $f(z)=z^2$, but I do not know what to say if the origin is added back.

Comment: I think you can show that if $f:X\to X$ is surjective, continuous and $f^{-1}(x)$ is finite for each $x$ then $f$ is a covering map. If that's the case then the answer for $\mathbb{C}$ is positive (i.e. there is no counterexample) because it is simply connected. And being simply connected would be the property you are looking for.

Comment: @freakish You would need a local homeomorphism assumption which is not necessarily a consequence of those you listed here, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you have a map $\mathbb{R}^n\to Y$ for some topological space $Y$, such that $|f^{-1}(y)|=2$ for all $y\in Y$.

I'll consider the particular case where you make the additional assumption:

*The map $f$ is "nice" in the sense that for all $y\in Y$, the two elements of $f^{-1}(y)$ are distant by more than some absolute constant $\varepsilon> 0$.*

Then, consider $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the restriction of $f$ to the open ball $B(x,\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$. Since bounded closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are compact, this restriction is a closed map. It is also continuous and bijective onto its range, [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339399/a-bijective-continuous-map-is-a-homeomorphism-iff-it-is-open-or-equivalently-i) it is a homeomorphism onto its range. It follows that $f$ is a [covering map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space).

Now since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply connected, $f$ is a [universal cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers) of $Y$, and since the fiber has two elements, it follows that $$\pi_1(Y)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$$

So there you are, under a pretty reasonable restriction on $f$, you see that the target space needs to have a very particular topology - it can't be $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself for instance.